# Assigning printf() result to a variable

Tags: c, printf

When I run this code without `\n` the output is **hello5** but with `\n` the output is **hello6**, can someone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int c;
  c = printf("hello\n");
  printf("%d",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `c = printf("hello++");` and you'll start to notice a pattern.

Comment: Yes now when I came to think of it this way It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function returns the total number of characters printed.

When you print `"hello\n"`, that's 6 characters, so `c` is 6.  When you print `"hello"`, that's 5 characters, so `c` is 5.

Comment: So `\n` is not ignored in this case and considered as a character.

Comment: @overkill Correct.  All characters are counted, including whitespace.

Comment: It's not "considered as a character", it _is_ a character. Specifically, the line feed character.